# Помогите правильно сконфигурировать hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: java, hibernate

Здравствуйте.
Хочу сделать Hibernate Search. Прочитал разные статьи на эту тему, в частности здесь: http://hibernate.org/search/documentation/getting-started/

Там приводится пример конфигурации hibernate.cfg.xml
В этом файле прописываются строчки:

```
<property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider">value="filesystem"</property>
<property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase">value="/var/lucene/indexes"</property>
```

Я понимаю, что первая строчка говорит о том, что индекс создавать в файловой системе, а вторая указывает путь до него.

Но дело в том, что я работаю в Windows и, видимо, в моём случае, путь к индексу будет выглядеть немного иначе.

Пишу так:

```
<property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider">value="filesystem"</property>
<property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase">value="D:\JDev\hg\indexes"</property>
```

Изначально в этой паке никаких индексов нет, и я предполагаю, что они должны после запуска приложения появиться, но "что-то идет не так"(с)

В момент открытия сессии session = sessionFactory.openSession();

Получаю ошибку в виде:

Starting Jetty on port 8888
   [WARN] unavailable
java.lang.NullPointerException
...

Что я не так делю, подскажите?

Answer (score 1):

Отвечу сам себе. Ибо сижу с этой проблемой весь день.
Кто бы мог подумать, что километры эксэпшенов могут возникнуть из-за кавычек!!! в файле hibernate.cfg.xml

Правильная запись будет выглядеть так:

```
<property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider">filesystem</property>
<property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase">D:/JDev/hg/indexes</property>
```

Теперь осталось причесать код и буду продолжать.